# Converting JDouble to Double (JSON library)

Tags: scala

I'm using https://github.com/json4s/json4s. How do I convert its values such as `JDouble`, `JBool` to corresponding Scala's data types -- `Double` and `Boolean`?

**UPDATE**:

```
scala> (json \ "status")
res8: org.json4s.JValue = JBool(false)

scala> (json \ "status").extract[Boolean]
<console>:16: error: No org.json4s.Formats found. Try to bring an instance of org.json4s.Formats in scope or use the org.json4s.DefaultFormats.
              (json \ "status").extract[Boolean]
```

Comment: Not sure, but try something like this `(jv \ "items" \ "type").extractOpt[String]` if it works!

Comment: @Shrey, what are jv, "items" and "type"? I have to correct it for my json structure to be able to try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code (https://github.com/json4s/json4s/blob/7c70e9664232ffee4acf24c8969424cd37957736/ast/src/main/scala/org/json4s/JsonAST.scala) shows that you just need to call the `JValue.values` method.

**UPDATE**: From your comment it seems that it's not so much that you have a `JDouble` and want to extract its `Double` value (and similarly extract a `Boolean` from a `JDouble`. Instead, you have a `JValue` 
and want to extract its value as a `Double` or `Boolean` (knowing in advance the expected type).
This can be done with `extract`, as explained in the *README* that you linked to:

```
(json \ "status").extract[Double]
```

or:

```
(json \ "status").extract[Boolean]
```

See also this test file for more examples:
https://github.com/json4s/json4s/blob/master/tests/src/test/scala/org/json4s/ExtractionExamplesSpec.scala

Comment: values method is not enough, it doesn't return the Scala's types.

Comment: Can you elaborate? `JDouble.values` returns a `scala.Double` and `JBoolean.values` returns a `scala.Boolean`. Isn't it what you were after?

Comment: `values` returns `Values` (capitalized) -- `(json \ "status").values ---
status: org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue#Values = false`, meaning it's `status` of type `org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue#Values` with value `false`.

Comment: That's because you need to bring an implicit `Formats` object in scope (again, as explained in the README). Just put this in your scope: `implicit val formats = DefaultFormats`

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in [Read Me](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/blob/master/README.md), heres how you do it.. :)

```
  import org.json4s._
  import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._

  implicit val formats = DefaultFormats 

  val json = parse("""
            {
                "mydouble" : 3.14,
                "isPie" : true
             }
    """) 

  val dbl = (json \ "mydouble").extractOpt[Double]
  //> dbl  : Option[Double] = Some(3.14)
  val bool = (json \ "isPie").extractOpt[Boolean] 
  //> bool  : Option[Boolean] = Some(true)
```